# Why did I get a -1 reputation for a downvote?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Can anyone explain why I got this -1 on Jun 30?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/267702/gonzobrains?tab=reputation

Thanks,
gb

Comment: FYI, we cannot see that you downvoted and what you downvoted on in your reputation history. (For good reasons of course)

Comment: You give a -1 vote somewhere.

Comment: don't let this discourage you from down voting, this isn't a game of acquiring reputation and hoarding it. I don't think enough people down vote enough dumb, useless duplicate answers. Down voting questions is FREE, that isn't done enough for sure.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod.  Wow, my first question on meta and I get so many downvotes.  I understand it *shouldnt* be a game, but now that employers and such look to see your rep here I think people do treat it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should say next to the `-1` the reason for the reduction similar to this -

[image]

**Others can't see this on your profile because the voting mechanism is anonymous.**

---

Taken from - [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

> #### You lose reputation when:
>
> - one of your questions or answers is voted *down/not useful*: **−2**
> - **you vote an answer *down/not useful*: −1**
> - ...

Comment: I get it that I get -1 reputation once I downvote an answer. But why does this cause-and-effect relationship exist e.g. to encourage answers in general and discourage people from disliking answers?

Comment: You're asking *why* you get a -1 for downvoting?

Comment: Yes but I've found the answer, thanks @Lix

Comment: @fuzzybee can you share the answer with us?

Comment: @Lior the answer is right in my question actually, it just makes sense now so don't go around downvoting answers freely

Comment: Cool, I already found a place and read up on it but thanks anyways.